# How to ensure That The SignalR Connection to .NET Client Is Up?

Tags: c#, .net, signalr

I have a simple **.NET client** listening to a specific **SignalR server running under an ASP.NET web application in IIS**.

Is there a good way to **ensure that this connection is always up**, by always I mean it should run with no problem for days, weeks ... 
Most cases when I check the connection (by raising events on server) after a day or even few hours, the connection is not there anymore, and before it worked fine.
Should I run a thread checking if the connection is up and restart if not every x minutes? Is there a more elegant solution for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SignalR Client exposes a few event handlers you can subscribe to be notified about changes to connection. Specifically you can be notified if the client lost the connection and is trying to reconnect (the `Reconnecting` event), if the client reconnected successfully (the `Reconnected` event) of if the connection has been stopped (the `Closed` event). There is also the `StateChange` event that is fired each time the `Connection.State` changes. [Here is a good article](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events) explaining connection lifetime events.

Comment: Can these events be received through .NET client as well?

Comment: It looks it can: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client#connectionlifetime, they have an example to `hubConnection.ConnectionSlow += () =>  method()`

Comment: How would you design it to keep alive the connection?

Comment: You can restart the connection in the `Connection.Closed` event (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.connection.closed(v=vs.118).aspx). You need to be careful with re-entering SignalR client code from the `StateChanged` event - in some cases the client holds a lock when calling this event and re-entering the stack may cause a deadlock.